# How to check if condition while inserting the database

Tags: php, php-5.6

I have one multidimensional array, this values i want to insert the database so i am doing like this, it is working fine, but i need one logic like before insert the values in database, i want to check two condition like **badge_number and pf_month** is already exist means i want to do omit the rows remaining rows i want to insert how can do?

---

remove the while loop and if condition means is working fine ,but now not working

---

UPDATE CODE

```
foreach($userDetails as $user){
    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO loan_history(pf_month,badge_number,first_name,pf_amount,loan_amount)VALUES('".$user['month']."','".$user['badgeNumber']."','".$user['name']."','".$user['pfAmount']."','".$user['loanAmount']."')");
}
```

```html
$userDetails=
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [month] => 01-2017
            [badgeNumber] => 4563215
            [name] => Kanniyappan
            [pfAmount] => 5000
            [loanAmount] => 9800
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [month] => 01-2017
            [badgeNumber] => 1453215
            [name] => Mahesh
            [pfAmount] => 6000
            [loanAmount] => 22000
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [month] => 01-2017
            [badgeNumber] => 7783215
            [name] => Asif
            [pfAmount] => 30000
            [loanAmount] => 92000
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [month] => 01-2017
            [badgeNumber] => 5632154
            [name] => Avinash
            [pfAmount] => 100000
            [loanAmount] => 650000
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [month] => 01-2017
            [badgeNumber] => 7832152
            [name] => Rohit
            [pfAmount] => 4100
            [loanAmount] => 5052
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [month] => 01-2017
            [badgeNumber] => 7754544
            [name] => Rajesh
            [pfAmount] => 64443
            [loanAmount] => 77454
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [month] => 01-2017
            [badgeNumber] => 9686786
            [name] => Suresh
            [pfAmount] => 98747
            [loanAmount] => 54451
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [month] => 01-2017
            [badgeNumber] => 9686786
            [name] => Mohan
            [pfAmount] => 85565
            [loanAmount] => 74754
        )

)

       foreach($userDetails as $user){
  $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM loan_history");
   while($loan = mysql_fetch_assoc($check)){
    $avail_month = $loan['pf_month'];
    $avail_badge = $loan['badge_number'];
    
    if($avail_month != $user['month'] && $avail_badge != $user['badgeNumber']){
     $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO loan_history(pf_month,badge_number,first_name,pf_amount,loan_amount)VALUES('".$user['month']."','".$user['badgeNumber']."','".$user['name']."','".$user['pfAmount']."','".$user['loanAmount']."')");
     if($sql){
      echo "success";
     }else{
      echo "Error".mysql_error();
     }
    }else{
     echo "Error".mysql_error();
    }
    
   }
  
 }
```

Comment: You can use INSERT IGNORE

Answer (score 0):

You can use INSERT IGNORE

**INSERT IGNORE** : If a record doesn't duplicate an existing record, MySQL inserts it as usual. If the record is a duplicate, the IGNORE keyword tells MySQL to discard it silently without generating an error.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO person_tbl (last_name, first_name) VALUES( 'Jay','Thomas');
```

Comment: Check my update code,but this also not working properly,inserting multiple times

Comment: My requirement is same month and same badge_number then only i want to stop ,suppose same badge_number but month is different means i want to insert the values how can do this

Comment: you can add unique index for multiple columns this is called a **Composite Key* you can add it in a following way

ALTER TABLE `table_name` ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(`badge_number`, `month`);

after adding this index when you insert a new row it will insert only if badge_number and month are different